# How can I change the language of my natbib bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, natbib, languages

I am using the `natbib` package for my bibliography. For documents in English, everything works fine.

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{tex/bibliography} % the file is called bibliography.bib
```

There are certain keywords like `and` and `edition` that belong to the English language. When writing a German document, like in my case, they have to be translated.

I started by editing the `plainnat.bst` file, but it turned out to be rather difficult, as different comma rules apply in German etc.

Is there a package or a convenient approach to get it in German?
I am already using the following for my document, but it does not apply to the bibliography.

```
\usepackage{ngerman} % this only applies to the content, not the bibliography
```

Comment: Natbib claims to be compatible with babel. Doesn't that imply that keywords are translated? Otherwise, you may load biblatex with the natbib=true option, which emulates natbib and translates the keywords in babel's main language. As for the problem of punctuation, it is easier to change than in .bst file – the biblatex syntax is a latex syntax.

Comment: @Bernard: Thank you for that hint. Maybe something was wrong in my configuration. I'll check that.

Comment: Preferably you should load babel as the last package.

Comment: `natbib` has its own command for specifying the punctuation, also much easier than tangling with the bst file.

Comment: @Bernard What the package says about compatibility is simply that it doesn't raise errors, when used together with it. But the styles are full of fixed words like "and" and there's no way to change them other than making new `.bst` files.

Comment: @egreg: I see. I never used natbib. I think mentioning babel in the doc is rather ambiguous. So probably a simple solution would be biblatex + "natbib=true" option? – unless it also emulates the fixed words…

Comment: @Bernard `biblatex` just emulates the commands proper to `natbib`, not its inner working, so the fixed words should respect the language setting.

Comment: In the meantime, I dug into the BibTeX language, which is really interesting. It's a stack-based language in 'reverse polish notation'. You can edit everything in there, but as noted in an answer to another question, that might by overkill because of your advice.